# OpenMP GCC Design Documentation

Tags: gcc, openmp

I am currently investigating the level of effort required to add a new hardware architecture target offload accelerator to GCC. I am specifically interested in how the code in libgomp interacts with the plugin code that supports offload to hardware accelerators. Is there any documentation that describes the following:

1. The design of libgomp and the interaction with the plugins and the code in the config directory?
2. The compiler code generated for OpenMP pragmas that interacts with the runtime. What functions are called in the runtime?
3. Documentation that describes how to proceed with the integration of new target offload hardware?

If this documentation exists, it will save me significant effort in source code analysis to understand the existing infrastructure. I really appreciate you taking the time to respond to these questions.

I have examined the latest GCC source code and google searched for documentation.

Comment: The documentation of gomp is available [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libgomp/) (accessible from Google in 1 minute). It is pretty small. Everything that is not in the documentation is found in the code or the mailing list. This is the way GCC works. You certainly need to get your hands dirty by looking the implementation. Besides, note GCC is not meant to be particularly modular as opposed to Clang (more generally LLVM).